# How to print the KQL result to ASCII table

Tags: kql

I am trying to print the results in ASCII tables as below

```
------------------------------------------------------
originalEventTimestamp       | text                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
------------------------------------------------------
2020-07-25 19:09:36.0604182  | abcd
2020-07-25 19:09:36.0570676  | abcd
2020-07-25 19:09:36.0505681  | abcd
2020-07-25 19:09:36.0454867  | abcd
```

Noticed *kql_raw_result* has the following methods, but non of them print in the above format:

```
Kqlmagic.results.ResultSet
_kql_raw_result_.__str__
_kql_raw_result_.raw_json
_kql_raw_result_.to_csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use to_dataframe() and then you can print it easily